# can't redirect to a default dashboard link when login angularJS

Tags: angularjs

in my login controller i redirected to index page

```
    location.href="index.html"
```

in `index.html` i used this code

```
    <body data-ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right topDropdownMenu">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dashboard/{{$root.tab.id}}">Dashboard</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#/voters/{{$root.tab.id}}">Voters</a>
    </div>
```

and this is my `mainCtrl` controller

```
    services.getElectionParties().success(function(data,status){
       $scope.tabs = data;
    });
```

i tried redirecting to "`#/dashboard"`. but i need to pass `tab.id` as url parameter on login by default
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple . use same `location.href` in `mainCtrl` to redirect by default

```
    services.getElectionParties().success(function(data,status){
         $scope.tabs = data;
         $scope.tab = data[0].id;
         location.href = "#/dashboard/"+$scope.tab.id;
    });
```

by these changes you will be redirected to your dashboard once your `mainCtrl` is loaded by default